# How can I count objects with specific condition from object list?

Tags: java, list

Suppose I add 4 objects:

Object 1 with a string "morning"

Object 2 with a string "afternoon"

Object 3 with a string "evening"

Object 4 with a string "morning"

How can I count number of objects that have string "morning" in the list?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just visit our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page for more information to use this site.

Comment: Questions on the site should be about specific programming problems. When you've got since code that's not working as it should you can post it here. What, exactly, are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
    for (String s : stringList  ){
        if(s.equals("Morning")){  //s.equalsIgnoreCase(Morning) or s.contains("Morning")
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("count = "+count);
```